# Rails 3 - "Undefined method 'comments_path' Error building shared form for comments using commentable polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, comments, polymorphic-associations

I'm having trouble building a form for comments, which i'm doing using a polymorphic relationship through 'commentable'.  I'm able to display comments now (if i seed them) so i think i'm really close.  The comment form is displaying as well, however when i go to submit it fails.

I'm sent to "/comments" and I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in CommentsController#create 

undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Application Trace
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:5:in `create' (  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment]) )
```

** First of all, why is it sending me to '/comments'??  That doesn't seem right.

Here's the relevant code, let me know if you need more.

models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  default_scope :order => 'comments.created_at DESC'
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable 
  ...
end
```

view (comments/form) - this is then rendered as a partial in Track#show

```
<% form_for [@commentable, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>

  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comments controller:

```
def create  
  @commentable = find_commentable  
  @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])  
  if @comment.save  
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully saved comment."  
    redirect_to :id => nil  
  else  
    render :action => 'new'  
  end  
end

def new
  @comment = Comment.new
end

private

def find_commentable  
  params.each do |name, value|  
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/  
      return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)  
    end  
  end  
  nil  
end
```

routes:

```
resources :tracks, :has_many => :comments
resources :comments
```

This is my first post ever so let me know if i can improve the question!  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in this code. I guess, you forget to set up `@track` or `@commentable` variable somewhere, where you call comments on it.

Try to examine application error trace to see where that happens.

Comment: Ok, wow solved it.  I'm going to checkoff this answer even tho if left some work to be done...  i added `@commentable` to Show in the Tracks Controller.  However that was giving me a no route error which i finally fixed by changing the route.rb to  `resources :tracks do`
      `resources :comments`
  `end`